# django cannot view database items in template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have data that I insert into my database but cannot view the items. I can see a `<ul>` index, but no data.

```
$ python3 manage.py shell
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from userdash.models import AssetList
>>> ls = AssetList.objects.get(id=2)
>>> ls
<AssetList: Mike's List>
>>> ls.items_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Items: Batcoin>, <Items: Drum set>, <Items: Dildo>, <Items: Koodie>]>
>>> ls.items_set.create(user_asset="5th Item", sell_asset=False)
```

in userdash/templates/userdash/list.html

```
{% extends 'userdash/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
<h1>List Page</h1>

{% endblock %}



{% block content %}

        <h2>{{ls.name}}</h2>


        <ul>
                {% for item in ls.items_set.all %}
                        <li>{{items.user_asset}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
        </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

in exchange2/userdash/models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class AssetList(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

        def __str__(self):
                return self.name

class Items(models.Model):
        currencylist = models.ForeignKey(AssetList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        user_asset = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        sell_asset = models.BooleanField()

        def __str__(self):
                return self.user_asset
```

output:

[html output](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1588384669.png)

The ul output indicates data is there, but it's not displaying it.

How do I properly display my database query in a django template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `{% for item in ls.items_set.all %}`, the loop-variable is named `item`, not `items`.

Replace

```
<li>{{items.user_asset}}</li>
```

with

```
<li>{{item.user_asset}}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You loop over `ls.items_set.all` with the variable `item`, but in the next line you use the name `items` (note the plural/singular).

Try to change your code to:

```
            {% for item in ls.items_set.all %}
                    <li>{{item.user_asset}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
```